# Print list using print statement in python

Tags: python

I have a list and need to print it. After print, my final output looks like below:

```py
['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

but the final output when I print should look like this:

```py
np.array(['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Let me show complete example
My Input:

```
values = np.array([6,5,3,4,1,2])
names = np.array(["x","y","z","a","b","c"])
n = 5
```

What i need to do:
Need to sort values and corresponding names, and print first 'n' names.
the print format has to be like this:

```
np.array(['b', 'c', 'z', 'a', 'y'])
```

my code:

```
combined=np.concatenate((numeric.reshape(numeric.size,1),labels.reshape(numeric.size,1)), axis=1)
sort_combined=combined[combined[:,0].argsort()]
sort_combined_n=list(sort_combined[0:(n+1),1])
print (sort_combined_n)
```

Comment: print('np.array(' + my_list + ')')

Comment: What is the reason to print out the list as python code?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I don't think hard-coding the type is what OP wants. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what is my list here'+my_list'?
My output is in list
outlist=some calculation
when i print(outlist) it returns:
['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']

print('np.array(outlist)') this is returning like below:
np.array(outlist), which is not i want

Comment: @rkatraga Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates what you are asking about. Also show an example run with all the output.

Comment: You can replace `my_list` with `outlist` if you wish. Since you don't provide any variable names in your question, I made up a very generic one.

Comment: @89f3a1c My first comment is a tongue-in-cheek answer that literally solves the OPs problem as stated. You are correct that it doesn't make sense. I think we are missing details here for a sensible question which is why I posted my second comment for clarification.

Comment: I added my complete problem code

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Is my question clear now?

Comment: This is heading in the correct direction. I just have a few comments/questions: 1. In your input, you have variables named `values` and `names` which are not used in your code. 2. Your code uses variables `numeric` and `labels` which are not declared anywhere. If you fix these, the code example will be much easier to work with.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you for the help. I solved it. Looks like I did a confused job of presenting the question. Will improve next time.

Answer (score 2):

That's how `print` works. It prints the actual list.

If you want to print anything else, say, for debug reasons, you'll have to add that manually.

Whether or not that is a good practice for debugging is another thing.

Answer (score 2):

You would literally have to use `print ("np.array(" + str(ARRAY_NAME) + ")")`. It doesn't seem in any way useful other than for debugging, so I don't know why you'd wanna use it.

Answer (score 2):

`print()`, by default, uses an object's `__str__()` method. What you probably want is its `__repr__()`. `print(repr(foo))` should achieve close to what you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to create a numpy array and print it try the following. Hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np
my_list = np.array(['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
print(my_list)
```